# I have written a python script . posting the initial few lines . objective is to get a file as attachment in email from the host

Tags: python

Here is my initial script

```
import smtplib
import socket
local_hostname=socket.gethostname()
host=socket.gethostname()
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

fromaddr="abc@xyz.com"
toaddr="abc@xyz.com"

#MIMEMultipart
msg=MIMEMultipart()

#Senders email address
msg['from']=fromaddr

#Receiver email address
msg['To']=toaddr

#The subject in the email 
msg['Subject']= 'ALERT NOTIFICATION FROM {host}"
```

But the message doesn't have the hostname in subject . it displays the same as in the line : ALERT NOTIFICATION FROM {host} . Basically need the host to be replaced by the actual host name of the server from where the email getting send . can anyone have any clue how can this be corrected . Many thanks

Comment: As an aside. it looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
msg['Subject'] = 'ALERT NOTIFICATION FROM {}'.format(host)
```

or

```
msg['Subject'] = f'ALERT NOTIFICATION FROM {host}'
```